# Transfer money between accounts in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I am writing a contract where I want to transfer money (present in the contract owners account and not the contract) to an account address passed to a function in the contract.

for some reason this code won't work

```
function payBill(uint value, address account) payable public {
account.transfer(value);
transactionCount += 1;
transactionAmount += value;
```

}

Comment: well, it won't compile as it stands...  `account` needs to be of type `address payable` in order to expose the `transfer` method.

Comment: Why do you want to write a contract function that does exactly what basic transfers do ?

Comment: A contract can only transfer from its own balance. To transfer ethers it should have been received previously or in the same transaction if the function is payable.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you transfer ethers, not money. You pass the amount you desire to transfer as **Value**, not as method parameter. And remember always update contract state before `transfer()` method, because on the example your contract is vulnerable to reentrancy attack. If `transfer()` method fails it will revert the state changes above. Read more [here](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/). Another problem with your contract is that your state is vulnerable to variables overflow. It's good idea to use this `SafeMath` contract for simple operations like addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract SafeMath {
    /**
    * @dev Multiplies two numbers, reverts on overflow.
    */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
        // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
        // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/pull/522
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b);

        return c;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Integer division of two numbers truncating the quotient, reverts on division by zero.
    */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0);
        // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

        return c;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Subtracts two numbers, reverts on overflow (i.e. if subtrahend is greater than minuend).
    */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Adds two numbers, reverts on overflow.
    */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);

        return c;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Divides two numbers and returns the remainder (unsigned integer modulo),
    * reverts when dividing by zero.
    */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0);
        return a % b;
    }
}

contract TestContract is SafeMath {
    uint public transactionCount = 0;
    uint public transactionAmount = 0;

    function payBill(address payable account) payable public {
        transactionCount = add(transactionCount, 1);
        transactionAmount = add(transactionAmount, msg.value);

        address(account).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer. one thing to add is that starting in Solidity 0.8 SafeMath is included in normal operations implicitly, so you don't need to do explicit calls to it